# Solving modular equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a procedure to solve this or is it strictly by trial and error?

$5^x \equiv 5^y \pmod {39}$ where $y > x$.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "solved"? There are infinite answers for both x and y with modular arithmetic.

Comment: Essentially, the first element to repeat in the sequence:
5^1 mod 39, 5^2 mod 39, 5^3 mod 39.....

Comment: Answer: `x = 0, y = 4` EDIT: `x = 4, y = 8`

Comment: x and y are greater than or equal to one

Comment: IIRC, these are called/related to [Discrete Logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). Which aren't easy compute.

Comment: @Mysticial: This problem is much easier than the general discrete logarithm problem. Not only because the numbers are small, but mostly because here we want $x$ in terms of $y$. See the answers below.

Answer (score 4):

Since the $\gcd(5, 39) = 1$ then $5^{x}$ has a multiplicative inverse $5^{-x}$. Multiplying both sides by the inverse, we get that $5^{y - x} = 1 \pmod{39}$.

By trial and error, we get that the order of $5$ is $4$ (that is $5^4 = 1 \pmod{39}$ and 4 is the smallest positive exponent that gives $1$). Then we know that $4 | y - x$, that is $y = 4 k + x$.

If you are wondering if there is another faster way to get the order of $5$, there is no general (much faster way) known way, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). There are ways to do it in something like $O(\sqrt{n})$, where n is the mod ($39$ in this case).

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite your problem as
$$5^{y-x}=1\bmod 39.$$
So we are trying to find the positive integers $k$ such that $5^k=1\bmod{39}$.
Since we can find the prime power factorization of $39$ easily, our problem reduces to finding the positive $n$ such that (simultaneously) $5^n=1\bmod 3$ **and** $5^n=1 \bmod{13}$.

If $p$ is a prime which does not divide $a$, then the *smallest* positive $d$ such that  $a^d=1 \bmod{p}$ is a *divisor* of $p-1$.

Let $a=5$ and $p=3$. Then $p-1$ has only the divisors $1$ and $2$. Obviously $5^1 \neq 1\bmod{3}$. So the smallest $d$ that works for $p=3$ is $d=2$.

Let $a=5$ and $p=13$. Then $p-1=12$, so our candidates for $d$ are the divisors of $12$. It is easy to check that $1$, $2$, and $3$ don't work. But $4$ does.

Now we want the smallest $d$ that works for both $3$ and $13$. This is the least common multiple of the $d$ that works for $3$ and the $d$ that works for $13$. The least common multiple of $2$ and $4$ is $4$.

We conclude that the least positive $d$ such that $5^d=1\bmod{39}$ is $4$. By a general theorem, the $n$ such that $5^n=1\bmod{39}$ are the multiples of $4$. So we can write $n=4k$, where $n$ ranges over the positive integers.

Thus in the original problem, the pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy your condition are all pairs $(x,x+4k)$. You say that you want $x\ge 1$, so the pairs are all pairs $(x,y)$ where $1\le x$ and $y-x$ is a positive multiple of $4$.

**Remark:** If instead of working with the small number $39$, we work with a huge number $m$, then the prime power factorization of $m$ can be computationally very difficult.

Even after we have factored $m$, things can be computationally very unpleasant, even in the simplest case where $m$ is prime, or a product of two primes. 
There are algorithms that are much better than the crude try everything approach, but still, they are not fast enough to deal with $m$ if it is $150$ digits long.

For small $m$, like our $39$, or even modestly large $m$, say of size less than $10^6$, there are programs that give virtually instantaneous answers.

Comment: I'm surprised no one is +1ing your answer.. It subsumes mine and explains everything much clearer..

Comment: @aelguindy: No problem, it will presumably be read by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since $39 = 3\cdot 13$ we can compute the order of $5\ ({\rm mod}\ 39)$ from its order mod $3$ and mod $13$.

First, mod $13\!:\ 5^2\equiv -1\ \Rightarrow\ 5^4\equiv 1;\ \ $ Second, mod $3\!:\ 5\equiv -1\ \Rightarrow\ 5^2\equiv 1\ \Rightarrow\ 5^4\equiv 1 $.

Thus $\:3,13\ |\ 5^4-1\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm lcm}(3,13)\ |\ 5^4-1,\:$ i.e. $\:39\ |\ 5^4-1,\:$ i.e. $\:5^4\equiv 1\pmod {39}$